# Resque workers failing silently with no logs or no debug information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

I have a piece of code code which runs some method and I have put that method inside the self.perform as below

```
class StartWorker
  @queue = :worker

  def self.perform
    puts "hello"
    Parser.find_all_by_class_name("Parser").first.sites.each do |s|
      site = Site.find(s.id)
      parser = Parser.new(site)
      parser.run
    end
  end
end
```

If I comment the def self.perform and end of this and run the file it is correctly showing the desired results but when I try to put this as a background task by uncommenting the same It is failing silently into the resque panel showing nothing .and also with no outputs in the command prompt

I am queuing this from resque-scheduler, inside my resque_schedule.yml

```
start_worker:
cron: "55 6 * * *"
class: StartWorker
queue: worker
args:
description: "This job starts all the worker jobs"
```

I tried putting some simple puts statements inside the the def self.perform method to check whether the control is passing inside the method or not but it seems the control is not even passing inside the self.perform method

also I tried to load the rails environment and required resque inside it but of no use
I have runned the bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE='*' script for all the above before making any changes

I tried Resque.info inside the rails console it is showing like this ,

```
 {:working=>0, :queues=>1, :failed=>1, :environment=>"development", :servers=>["redis://localhost:6379/0"], :pending=>0, :processed=>1, :workers=>1}
```

Any Ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 4):

1. Have you checked the resque-web panel to see what that failed job is?
2. Make sure you restart workers after any changes.
3. If you're not seeing 'hello' in your logs anywhere (specifically log/worker.log or where ever yours log to) then the function simply isn't happening.
4. `bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE='*'` should be `bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*`
   , just incase you really did quote the wildcard.

Comment: resque-web panel is not showing any failed jobs I am just seeing 1 worker working but with no outputs or nothing inside the logs when i tried 'bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*'It is throwing error like **rake aborted!
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass **

Comment: right! so your worker wont actually start. you need to find the nil object that it's trying to .map .

Comment: yes but how to get where this error is coming from ? when using without the self.perform method or without resque  that StartWorker class runs great producing the desired outputs

Comment: `bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=* --trace`. --trace can be added to any rake call

Comment: I found solution for this actually the rails environment was not at all loading the class because of its convention over configuration I needed to change file name to start_worker.rb which is under lib/jobs where that class was present I thought of just loading directory inside the application.rb was enough but namings also does play a huge part Thanks!

Comment: For others that arrive here looking for help with a similar problem, I had forgotten to load the Rails environment in /lib/tasks/resque.rake with
`task "resque:setup" => :environment`

If Resque can't find the worker class, it seems to fail "silently" - the failed count goes up but you get no further error information.

The way I worked it out is also probably useful to others - add `VVERBOSE=true` when you run the rake resque:work task, i.e.
`bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE='*' VVERBOSE=true`. Yes, that is VVERBOSE with a double 'V' for Very Verbose debug logging.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
Resque::Scheduler.configure do |c|
  c.verbose = Rails.env.development? # or just true
end
```

Ruby: `3.0.3`,
Resque: `2.2.0`,
Resque-Scheduler `4.5.0`,
Rails: `6.1.4.4`